# Peroblem with laarvel project deployment to cpanel

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, laravel-8

Hope you guys are well, I have faced a problem deploying my laravel project on Cpanel. When I am hit my route URL or a root URL then it show me "404 not found"

This is the root url : https://laravel.tamimikbal.com/project1/

I have written this code on my root .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

And this the public/.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.htaccess` is not redirecting properly to the `public` directory. I can access and navigate on your site using "https://laravel.tamimikbal.com/project1/public/".

Try this as the contents of the `.htaccess` file in your root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Sorry sir, Its't working, Can you give me another solution, please

Answer (score 0):

I can better understand if you put how is the routing url should be looks like
anyway you can try this code:

```
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
```

while you don't have `www.` and `https` is activated on your domain you can use this code to make redirect from `www.` to `none www` and from `http` to `https`

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

the rout request and file directory you can use this code

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css|webp|JP2)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

if you want to redirect you system files to `404 page` edit this code and replace your system folder and your `404` routing page

```
RewriteRule ^system/(.*) index.php?route=your 404 page [L]
```

Comment: This is the root URL: When anyone hits this URL I want to show the home page. But now I have to enter this https://laravel.tamimikbal.com/project1/public/ for the homepage, But I and this https://laravel.tamimikbal.com/project1/

Comment: try this:#RewriteRule ^project1/public$ project1 [L]

Comment: Sorry sir, Its't working, Can you give me another solution, please

Comment: Okay i have tested this following code on my cpanel and it's worked with no error just change your domain and your root folder pleas have me know if it success with you

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder/
RewriteRule (.*) /folder/$1 [L]